# Close connection TeamViewer in my command line

Tags: command-line, cmd

i want close my connection (TeamViewer) with command line... it's possible ?
for connect in command line it's:

```
teamviewer.exe -i <ID> --Password <Password>
```

but for disconnect ???

someone help me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just cancel the process, and the entire program will exit. How you do so depends on if the program is running in the foreground or in the background.

Background:

```
Taskkill /IM teamviewer.exe /F
```

Foreground:

```
CTRL-C, or CTRL-Break
```

Comment: Teamviewer is a GUI window, so ctrl-c and ctrl-break won't do anything.  The other comment I would make is that `/F` to force the window closed is not needed unless the window is not responding.  Taskkill will otherwise gracefully close the window, without `/F` (perhaps prompting to close the connection so /F may be needed in this case)

Comment: I do not want to stop TeamViewer but finished connection I have with another computer. in the task manager teamviewer does not create a process for each connection. that's why I have difficulties: (